# InnoDB database locking blocks threads

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, hibernate

I have a really weird issue with a project I'm working with. I would appreciate if someone could point me to a right direction here.

// Setup

There are multiple web servers and a loadbalancer is in front of them. Servers are handling requests that might come in multiple parts and parts can be handled by different servers. These multi-part requests should be combined to a one single transaction that is going forward once all the parts are received. 
The server that does the final processing doesn't matter, but only one server can do it. Other servers that receive the previous parts should just mark the part received, store the data and give a immediate response back.

For now I'm using database table to handle the synchronization between nodes. 
The basic idea is that when a server gets a part it tries to acquire the lock with a transaction id coming with the rquest. This is done by trying to insert a row to a Lock table with the txid as a primary key. If insert is successful, that server gets the lock and processes the part it received, by storing it to database checks if other parts have been received and returns a response immediately if not.

// The Problem

The problem I have is that the threads seem to randomly lock at the database and thus freezing the whole processing. I have debugged it to the point that in a situation where multiple requests come to processing at the same time they just get stuck at trying to acquire the lock and ultimately timeout after 30 seconds. Few of the first requests might get processed or not it seems to be random but even something like 7 concurrent requests block the database.

To me there should not be any way how this could get stuck and I'm fresh out of ideas.

// Information

I am using MySQL with an InnoDB engine. Servers are running Java code and Hibernate is used as a ORM layer to access the DB.

The Lock table:

```
CREATE TABLE `lock` (
    `id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `expiryDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    `issueDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The id is the transaction id used to combine the parts.

I have an basic interface that manages the lock accessing.

```
public interface LockProviderDao {

    public boolean lock(String id);
    public boolean unlock(String id);
}
```

And a implementation of that class that uses Hibernate to access database.

```
@Override
public boolean lock(String id) {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
    Lock lock = new Lock(id);
    Transaction tx = null;
    boolean locked = false;

    try {
        // Try to lock
        tx = session.beginTransaction();

        session.save(lock);
        tx.commit();
        locked = true;

    } catch(Exception e) {
        if(tx != null) {
            tx.rollback();
        }

    } finally {
        session.close();
    }

    return locked;
}

@Override
public boolean unlock(String id) {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
    boolean status = true;
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        Lock lock = (Lock) session.load(Lock.class, id);

        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.delete(lock);
        tx.commit();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        if(tx != null) {
            tx.rollback();
        }
        status = false;

    } finally {
        session.close();
    }

    return status;
}
```

Seems simple enough. Here is the code that does the processing. This thread has a Hibernate session opened already so the Session opened inside the lock and unlock methods is a nested Session, if that makes any difference.

```
int counter = 0;
boolean lockAcquired = false;
do {
    // Try to acquire the lock
    lockAcquired = this.lockProviderDao.lock(txId);

    if (!lockAcquired) {
        // Didn't get it try a bit later
        try {
            Thread.sleep(defaultSleepPeriod);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        if (counter >= defaultSleepCycles) {
            return;
        }
        counter++;
    }

} while (!lockAcquired);

// DO THE PROCESSING HERE ONCE LOCK ACQUIRED

// Release the lock
this.lockProviderDao.unlock(txId);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would lock **after** inserting the data. This means, that you would have to change your algorithm to something like this:

1. Begin transaction
2. Insert the fragment to database
3. Commit transaction
4. Begin transaction
5. Count number of framgents inserted / exit, if not equal to expected fragment count
6. Insert a row, that indicates that fragments will be processed (e.g. your lock row). If this fails, fragments have been processed or are being processed (= rollback)
7. Commit transaction
8. Begin transaction
9. Read fragments (and verify that they still exist)
10. Process fragments
11. Delete lock and fragments (verify they still exist)
12. Commit transaction

If you need to increase reliability, you have three options:
 1. Use JMS with JTA to control program flow
 2. Have your client poll the server for status and start processing, if all parts have been received, but processing has not started yet or has been stalled
 3. Create a scheduler that starts processing, if same conditions apply